# CSS Scaled Div Centring

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having an issue centring a `<div id='divTwo'>` inside another `<div id='divOne'>`. This is normal an easy thing to do, however in this instance i have `transform: scale();` with `transform-origin: 50% 50% 0px;` applied on 'divTwo'

```css
#divOne {
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#divTwo {
    width: 1024px;
    height: 768px;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
    border-left: 131px solid #333333;
    border-right: 131px solid #333333;
    border-top: 47.5px solid #333333;
    border-bottom: 47.5px solid #333333;
    border-radius: 55px;
}
```

if the scale applied to the transform and the window is larger than the outerWidth(), 'divTwo' has no issue centring. However when the 'divTwo' is scaled and the window is smaller or equal to the outerWidth(). The div will no longer centre, instead it will place its centre point to be right side of the browser, resulting if half the of 'divTwo' being off the right hand-side of the browser. Changing `transform-origin: 50% 50% 0px;` to `transform-origin: 0% 50% 0px;` works so long as you don't scale vertically, and vice versa.

jsfiddle example : https://jsfiddle.net/yvyz49zp/

Thank you. I feel like am missing something of obvious.

Comment: I would say you're going about this wrong. Instead of using the border as a style in of itself, it should be a separate div underneath it

Comment: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yvyz49zp/), like this ? it didn't work. also want it so that i can change just the width and height and the "device" is responsive. Please could you give and example, do you mean create the boarder with a div inside or use a div inside with the same boarder information?

Comment: You linked to the exact same fiddle...

Comment: Alternative https://jsfiddle.net/jacelaf/kg2zawsL/ <-- this works better but still isn't perfect, vertical axis does the weird offset thing.

Answer (score 0):

I knocked this up relatively quickly in jsfiddle - no javascript needed. Just play around with the values until you get something you like.

**Code:**

```css
body {
    background: lightblue;
}

#container {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 50%;
    right: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(50%, -50%);
}
#dummy {   
    margin-top: 75%; /* Using the dummy is the trick - it locks the aspect ratio (at 4:3 in this case) */
}
#device {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10%;
    bottom: 10%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: #333;
    border-radius: 10%;
}

#screen {
    position: absolute;
    width: 70%;
    height: 80%;
    background: #0f0;    
    right: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="dummy"></div>
    <div id="device">
        <div id="screen"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this works great. but a user can't select the scale value of the device should be or the initial size of the device, it misses my needs. I have one working by manipulating margin-left https://jsfiddle.net/jacelaf/wdcmyx21/. I kind of need the scale there. was hoping to reduce the jQuery involved.